# How to make my LaunchImage load at the same time as the application?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

As the application loads, I want to make an image load at the same time, for example, a line would elongate form either side as the application loads, and when it has finished, the line would have reached its maximum length. I have seen this in a few websites, like [rime arodaky](http://www.rime-arodaky.com/) for example, but I want to this for an iOS application. I have searched on Google but couldn't find anything!

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The launch process if we REALY simplify it to accommodate your question, can be split into two parts.

The first part you do not have any control over, and during which a launch image is shown.and it ends with a delegate call-back on the application delegate called

`applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

The second part is you might have some application specific behaviour which requires no activity from the user but you app still isn't interactive.
You need to implement such a progress bar yourself. There is no built in support for this in any of the app templates in Xcode.

You can only do what you want during this second phase. But you have absolutely no control over the first phase, except for that static non-animated launch image.

Comment: It can't even be a .gif? Would that be the "Ketchapp" page in their apps for example?

Comment: No. it needs to be a PNG.

Comment: In iOS 8 you can have a bit smarter, resizable "launch image" utilising the launch image storyboard and auto layout. But it will still not be animated.
Apple generally discourages to do what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add a photo as a launch image, launch image is just an image.Then you can add the animation when your first view controller appears.You can fake it this way.